# Is there a word for a skeptical thought?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

We have:

- **critic:** a person giving criticism
- **criticism:** the practice of judging the merits and faults of something
- **critique:** one specific item of criticism

And we also have:

- **skeptic:** a person giving skepticism
- **skepticism:** the question attitude or doubt towards a putative knowledge or belief

So I wonder whether we have something like **skeptique** – a skeptical thought – or not. As my spell checker notes, this word doesn't exist. Obviously it has a skepticism towards the word.

See more: [Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism), [skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skepticism) in Wikipedia

Comment: Your brief definition of **critique** is not correct. A critique is a detailed assessment.

Comment: It's possible to say "John offered three minor critiques on my code."

Comment: A critic is not a person giving criticism. A critic is a person who writes reviews of movies, plays, art shows and books.

Comment: You cannot give skepticism. You are or you are not a skeptic or you are or are not skeptical about something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there *should* be such a word, but there isn't. You can use skeptical as an adjective and say "I'm going to give a skeptical review of [something]".  You could also say "skeptical analysis" or "write a skeptical essay".

("Critique" is a fairly obvious borrowing from French. In French *une critique* may translate to "a critic" or "a critique" according to context. "Critic" may have come from French, or directly from Latin, but came into English much earlier than "critque". French has a word *un sceptique* but it means "a skeptic", and doesn't have the range of meanings.)

Comment: He wrote a critique of the book. Meaning: a critical review.

Answer (score 0):

There is the word **skepsis** in the dictionary, but I have never seen it used.

Comment: dictionaries define "skepsis" as "skeptical philosophy" rather than a single instance of skeptisism.

Answer (score 0):

A specific piece of skepticism could be called a **skeptosis** from the Greek.